# Is the "new activity on a starred question highlighting" missing, poorly visible or removed?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, status-completed, design

I'm fairly certain that if there was new activity on a question I favorited/starred (as denoted by the blue "1"), when I clicked the favorites tab, any of those with new activity would be highlighted.

Since the style update, this seems to be either missing or removed. If it's missing, is this a bug, or have I just done something wrong. If it's removed, how can I tell which of the questions have been updated.

If the style is just not (very) visible, can we increase the contrast between the colors please?

[image]

I'm using Safari 8.0.2 (10600.2.5) on OS X Yosemite.

I favorited *this question* to check. The issue is the same:

[image]

Comment: I do see this highlight in my profile on Firefox on Windows, and it is very visible and hard to miss.

Comment: Works with chrome and firefox on Mac too. But I got a situations where there is a row highlighted without any blue "number".

Comment: @Krishnabhadra, would you mind testing Safari too please?

Comment: @JamesWebster I tested on OS X yosemite, Safari 8.0 and there is a very visible yellow highlight. The favorite count is showing as 8, but only 3 questions highlighted. I believe, there are 8 activities across 3 questions.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra yeah, that seems reasonable for the 8=3. I wonder what's happening wrong on mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever was causing this issue seems to have been resolved. I can see the highlighting again.